# SELECT statement to Return a Count for Each Row in Sybase Table

Tags: sql, sybase

While working on a MongoDB/Node back-end environment I am needing to run some ETLs to pull in data from a previous Sybase environment. I am far less familiar with SQL than I am with Mongo/Node.

The following SELECT statement finds the `count` for a particular record (row of data) in the `bl_serv_staffmember_xref` table:

```
SELECT Count()
   FROM  "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"
   WHERE ( "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"."staff_member_id" = 129 ) AND 
         ( "bl_serve_staffmember_xref"."isactive" = 1 );
```

What I need to do is generate a SELECT statement that will return data with that count for EACH row in the table. How would I go about doing that?

I tried this:

```
SELECT Count()
    FROM  "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"
   WHERE   ( "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"."staff_member_id" is NOT NULL ) AND 
         ( "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"."isactive" = 1 )   ;
```

But this just returns one *total* count:

```
Count()
1   2,452
```

rather than a count for *each* `staff_member_id`, which is what I need.

This is my desired result:

```
staff_member_id     assignment_count
1                   23
2                   12
3                   16
```

Comment: The count for each row would be "1".  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you mean for each staff_member_id ??'

Comment: Yes. For each staff_member_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use count(*) and group by eg:

```
SELECT bl_serv_staffmember_xref.staff_member_id, Count(*)
FROM  "bl_serv_staffmember_xref"
WHERE ( "bl_serve_staffmember_xref"."isactive" = 1 )
GROUP BY bl_serv_staffmember_xref.staff_member_id
```

Comment: Thanks, @scaisEdge. `GROUP BY` was the key.